# How can i cast a date format to zulu format in snowflake?

Tags: sql, casting, type-conversion, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I'm trying to convert all my date format to Zulu (ISO 8601) Format in my query

Need to convert `2022-03-17`  to `2022-03-17T00:00:00Z`

I'm only able to cast into TIMESTAMP_LTZ,TIMESTAMP_NTZ,TIMESTAMP_TZ

```
2020-03-17 00:00:00.000 +0100
2020-03-17 00:00:00.000
2020-03-17 00:00:00.000 +0100
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give you want you want, assuming you are just trying to display the date in this specific format:

```
SELECT TO_char('2022-03-17'::timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"');
```

Comment: This Works!!,appreciate ur help